# If I created a process, does it mean that I will always be able to terminate it?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, process

Say, if I created a process using [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs, does it means that calling [TerminateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)`(PROCESS_INFORMATION.hProcess)` will always kill that process no matter what context my host process is running in (low privileged user, built-in Guest, etc)?

Comment: All the information you need seems to be on the documenting pages behind those links.... Did you read them?

Comment: In the documentation for TerminateProcess I read: "The function [...] requests cancellation of all pending I/O. The terminated process cannot exit until all pending I/O has been completed or canceled." That could be read as indicating that if the I/O doesn't honor the cancel request the process cannot be terminated. I bet you one could write a driver for demonstration purposes, and e.g. with NFS over laggy lines may have long stalls.

Comment: @PeterSchneider At the driver level there all sorts of things you can do to prevent the process from being terminated, including replacing TerminateProcess with your own implementation.

Comment: @Ross I'm not sure what a file system or device driver would have to do with TerminateProcess. (Could it really replace it?)

Comment: @PeterSchneider Drivers have full access to memory. They can change anything, do anything.

Comment: @RossRidge Although that's not what the OP was aiming at, the answer to his question then is a resounding No. No, " TerminateProcess(PROCESS_INFORMATION.hProcess)" *will not* "always kill that process."

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I was obviously talking about a "stock" operating system configuration.

Comment: I understood that much, and I was having a stock driver in mind which would block termination. (The "driver for demonstration purposes" was just that, for demonstration.) There are always bugs, so obviously a buggy stock driver can prevent process termination; the trivial case. But even in normal operation a stock driver may block termination. My idea was along the lines of an atomic operation (hence NFS) that is stalled in mid-operation so that neither roll back nor completion are possible. Defective hard disks have made my machine unresponsive, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but according the documentation you should always be able to successfully terminate process using the handle returned in the PROCESS_INFORMATION. In Windows security model permissions are normally only checked against the handle being used, nothing else. According to the MSDN documentation on [Process Security and Access Rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429.aspx):

> The handle returned by the CreateProcess function has **PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS** access to the process object.

The documentation for [CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880.aspx) supports this with:

> This security descriptor may not allow access for the caller, in which case
>   the process may not be opened again after it is run. The process handle is
>   valid and will continue to have full access rights.

The only permission requirement givein in the documentation for [TerminateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714.aspx) is:

> The handle must have the **PROCESS_TERMINATE** access right.

So any handle return by CreateProcess and CreateProcessAsUser should have necessary and sufficient access-rights to allow killing the new process using TerminateProcess.